# CSV Create a new column removing spaces

Tags: shell-script

I have a large csv file which contains multiple columns. I want the spaces to be removed from the first column and want to create that as a new column.

Example...

**Input:**

```
a b,xyz,d e f    
a b c,xyz,d e f    
a b c d,xyz,d e f
```

**Output:**

```
ab,a b,xyz,d e f   
abc,a b c,xyz,d e f   
abcd,a b c d,xyz,d e f
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **sed**:

```
sed 'h;s/,.*/,/;s/ //g;G;s/\n//' data.csv
```

Explained:

```
h - stash current line to the hold space
s/,.*/,/ - remove everything after the first comma
s/ //g - remove spaces
G - append the line from the hold space back to the pattern space
s/\n// - remove extra newline, as left by G
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` with standard tools:

```
$ paste -d ',' <( cut -d ',' -f 1 file | tr -d ' ' ) file
ab,a b,xyz,d e f
abc,a b c,xyz,d e f
abcd,a b c d,xyz,d e f
```

`paste` combines the input from the two given files with a comma as the delimiter.

The first file is produce by a process substitution which extracts the first comma-delimited column of the file and removes its spaces.

The second file is simply the original unmodified file.

Comment: For plain *POSIX* shells this also works:  `cut -d, -f1 file | tr -d ' ' | paste -d, - file`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="," } { col=$1; gsub(/ /, "", col); print col,$0 }' file
```

Use commas as input and output column separators. Extract first column and sub out spaces. Output the modified first column followed by the original line.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` solution assuming a file `test.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
   IFS=',' read -ra fields <<<"$line"
   (IFS=','; echo "${fields[0]//\ /},${fields[*]}")
done <"test.txt"

exit
```

This takes advantage of [IFS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) to read the values of the csv into an array and output them.  Read each line of `test.txt` into a string, then read this line into an array by splitting on commas.  Print the first element of this array with spaces removed, then the entire array.  A quoted array using `*` will output the elements separated by `IFS`, which we previously set to a comma.  The inline declaration of `IFS` in the `read` statement and inside a subshell `()` will preserve the value of `IFS` for the rest of the script's execution.

Answer (score 0):

with the great [Miller](http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html) is:

`mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output \
put '$newField=gsub($1," +","")' \
then reorder -f newField input.csv`

`$1` is the first field. Than I apply a regex search and replace to obtain the new field.